# websocket spring boot setup

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I have a spring boot application. I am trying to add the websocket piece to it. The problem is my angular client can't connect to it. I used smart websocket client google plugin, but still not able to connect. Here is the setup.

I am using Intellij Idea on localhost. the spring boot application is running on localhost:8080. I can see the WebSocketSession is runnign from intellij idea console.

Here is the setup:

```
    @Slf4j
    @RestController
    public class WebsocketController {

         @MessageMapping("/ws-on/hello")
         @SendTo("/ws-on/greetings")
    public UserStateIndicator greeting(UserStateIndicator indicator) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        log.debug("websocket " + indicator.toString());
        return indicator;
    }
}




@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/ws-on");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-on")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

my angular is running on localhost:4200.
I used ws://localhost:8080/ws-on as the url from StompJS to connect.
My question is how do I find the websocket url to connect, and how do I know the websocket is running on the spring boot server?

Answer (score 0):

finally I figured it out. Because I am using SockJS on both angular and spring boot, so, the URL is actaully http not ws. the correct url to connect is then http://localost:8080/ws-on